# when i add in buildozer.spec jar file my android app have authorization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, kivy

I add in buildozer.spec:

```
android.add_jars = libs/android/zbar.jar
```

And my android app "Permission denied". Authorization made with django and restdjango. In PC app work normaly. Why?

If i delete this code from buildozer.spec my android app work normaly too. Why?